# ASP.NET Core web.config requestFiltering not overriding applicationhost.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to upload large files to an API controller action in my ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 application. To that end I've been trying to figure out how to allow this through IIS Express which is how I'm running the application through Visual Studio. As suggested, this should be possible by adding a `web.config` file to the project root with the following contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Configuration for IIS integration -->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 2 GB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, this doesn't have any effect as the application just returns `HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found`, indicating the request is too large. It seems as if those settings are locked by the IIS so the `web.config` isn't overriding them. Yes, I'm also using attributes such as `[DisableFormValueModelBinding]` and `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` on the controller action.

Instead I found that it works by adding the same configuration to the site in the `applicationhost.config` in the `\.vs\config` folder:

```xml
  <location path="MySite">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00" />
      <httpCompression>
        <dynamicTypes>
          <add mimeType="text/event-stream" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
      </httpCompression>
      <!-- Everything above this point is auto-generated -->
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <!-- 2 GB -->
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

This file, however, is not tracked in GIT and it doesn't seem like a good solution to add it to GIT either.

Is there some security reason or other for why the `web.config` seemingly is not allowed to override the `applicationhost.config`? Or is there a solution that I just haven't been able to figure out?

Comment: Don't know why there is no answer to this when it must be a very common problem. Alas I ended up reverting to just using POST instead of GET which I guess made more sense anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I added a web.config with this

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- This will handle requests up to 700MB (CD700) -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="737280000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

posted too soon. The above solution worked for iis express server but did not for docker. Then I updated the entry

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 100000000; //100MB
        });
```

Then decorate controllers with     `[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]`

Those solutions solved locally and in prod for me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but it doesn't seem to be any different from the configuration I posted except the number is lower, which wouldn't solve my problem. Also, a suggestion when you submit code on SO: please avoid using pictures - I can't really copy-paste that.

Comment: solution update hope it resolves ur issue ;) good luck